# σ-algebras generated by J

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I understand the definition of $σ$-algebra but I have difficulty solving some examples to find $σ$-algebra
for example:
If $J=\{ \{x \} : x ∈ R\}$
or
If $J= \{ \{x \} : x ∈ Q\}$
How I can find $σ(J)$ ??

Comment: Hi...I suggest you look at this for better formatting your question. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "finding" $\sigma(J)$, since in both cases you mentioned, the $\sigma$-algebra will have infinite cardinality. In fact this is exactly the purpose of the notation $\sigma(J)$, which is to describe a large $\sigma$-algebra without listing its elements.

To get a feel for the measurable sets, start by thinking of all the sets in $J$ -- suppose you're constructing a $\sigma$-algebra over the reals. What makes $J$ not a $\sigma$-algebra? Well firstly in both examples, $\emptyset$ and $\mathbf{R}$ aren't in $J$, so those must be included. The set $\{1/2\}$ is in $J$, but $\mathbf{R}\setminus \{1/2\}$ isn't in $J$, so that must be added because $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complementation. Also $\{1/3\}$ is in $J$ but $\{1/2,1/3\}$ is not in $J$, so it must be added since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions.

Essentially you proceed this way and stop exactly when the $\sigma$-algebra conditions are all met.